# Is there anyway to find std::tuple elements are all same type or not?

Tags: c++, templates, stdtuple

I would like to figure out true / false based on all of elements in std::tuple are same type or not.

for example

```cpp
std::tuple<int, int, int> t = { 1, 1, 1};
auto A = all_same(t);

std::tuple<int, float, int> t = { 1, 1.0, 1};
auto B = all_same(t);
```

here, A is true, B is false

anyway to do this?

Comment: Why you want `1!=1.0`? Do you know if you try `cout << 1==1.0` you'll get `true`?

Comment: @273K The duplicate does not answer the question since the conditions are assumed to be independent, in this question they are not.

Comment: @Q `all_of` there is a clear hint of a single condition to all tuple elements, and *whether they all fulfill the above condition*.

Comment: @273K That is true but I also think there is clear, non-duplicate answer to this searchable-in-the-future question that OP wants and could be simply provided.

Answer (score 3):

C++17 solution with fold expressions:

```
#include <tuple>

template<typename Head, typename...Tail>
constexpr bool all_same(const std::tuple<Head,Tail...>&){
    return (std::is_same_v<Head,Tail> && ...);
}

constexpr bool all_same(const std::tuple<>&){
    return true; // This is reasonable, right?
}


int main() {
            std::tuple<int, int, int> t1{ 1, 1, 1};
          static_assert(all_same(t1));

          std::tuple<int, float, int> t2{ 1, 1.0f, 1};
          static_assert(!all_same(t2));
          std::tuple<> t3{};
          static_assert(all_same(t3));
}
```

Maybe you want to use alternatives/additions to `std::is_same_v`:

- `std::is_convertible`, although you should check both pairs since it is not symetric.
- `std::swappable` might be the symetric version of `is_convertible` in this sense.
- Adding `std::decay` if you want `const float&` and `float` to be considered equals.

Answer (score 2):

The types of the tuple `std::tuple<A,B,C,D>` are all the same when `std::tuple<A,B,C,D>` and `std::tuple<B,C,D,A>` are the same type.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template <typename First, typename... T>
struct all_same_type {
    constexpr static bool value = std::is_same_v< std::tuple<First,T...>,
                                                  std::tuple<T...,First>>;
};

template <typename... T>
struct all_same_type<std::tuple<T...>> : all_same_type<T...> {};

template <typename... T>
constexpr bool all_same_type_v = all_same_type<T...>::value;

int main() {
    std::tuple<int, int, int> t = { 1, 1, 1};
    std::cout << all_same_type_v< decltype(t)> << "\n";

    std::tuple<int, float, int> u = { 1, 1.0, 1};
    std::cout << all_same_type_v< decltype(u)> << "\n";
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/PEzPbfG6x):

```
1
0
```

Comment: Small issue is the missing `std::tuple<>` case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way of doing this using [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) and [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

//for returning result based on both "type and value"
template<typename First, typename... Rest>
bool allSame(const std::tuple<First, Rest...> &tup ) requires(std::is_same_v<First, Rest> && ...)
{
    return std::apply([](const auto&... nth)
    {
        return (true == ... == nth  );
    }, tup);    
}
//version that always returns false if any type mismatch
template<typename First, typename... Rest>
bool allSame(const std::tuple<First, Rest...> &tup ) requires (... || !std::is_same_v<First, Rest>)
{    
    return false;
}

int main(){
    std::tuple<int, int, int> t = { 1, 1, 1};
    std::cout << allSame(t); //prints 1 

    std::tuple<int, float, int> t2 = { 1, 1.0, 1};
    std::cout << allSame(t2); //prints 0  

    std::tuple<int, int, int> t3 = { 1, 8, 1};
    std::cout << allSame(t3); //prints 0
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Wjbd5dv8M)

---

**Note**

If you don't care about the values, then it is **trivial** to replace the body of the first template with `return true;` as shown in this [modified demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ofaKfb6hv)

Comment: I don't think OP cares about the values. Only about types.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Looking at the code in OP's given question I think they do care about values. Anyways it is **trivial** to just replace the body(the lambda expression part) of the first template with just `return true;` as shown in [this demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ofaKfb6hv). This can be a simple exercise for OP. I've added a note at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct all_same_type : std::bool_constant<[](){
        if constexpr (sizeof...(Ts) == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            using First = std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<Ts...>>;
            return (std::is_same_v<First, Ts> && ...);
        }
    }()>
{
};

template <typename T>
struct all_same_inner_type;

template <typename... Ts>
struct all_same_inner_type<std::tuple<Ts...>> : all_same_type<Ts...> {};

template <typename...Ts>
constexpr bool all_same_inner_type_v = all_same_inner_type<Ts...>::value;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3dM5TM8es)